# How can I convert PEM file to string for ssh to ec2 using JSch library

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, jsch, pem

I am trying to SSH to EC2 using JSch Library from Java code. I referred this link in SO [How can I use .pem files content as a string in ec2 connection using JSch library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621836/how-can-i-use-pem-files-content-as-a-string-in-ec2-connection-using-jsch-librar) and tried couple of things as mentioned below but in vain. Can someone please guide me on how to achieve my objective?

**Objective**

I have a PEM file like this. I dont want to store my PEM file anywhere in AWS, hence my approach is to extract an equivalent string that I can encode and store in database and decode it from java for passing the parameter to `addIdentity` method that takes these parameters:

```
addIdentity(String name, byte[] prvkey, byte[] pubkey, byte[] passphrase)
    throws JSchException
```

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIepsdfAIBAAKCAQEAtBk068z
...
xVNdhlDy6asdk9wsdQ==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

For my objective, my `addIdentity` method would be like this I believe:

```
addIdentity ("username","{privatekey string converted to byte array}",null, null)
```

I am trying to understand how that string can be formed? I am very new to cryptography, but during this process I learnt that since my PEM has `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`, it's PKCS1 format. Does JSch support PKCS1 format or it needs to be converted to PKSC8?

Secondly, I learnt that the body is encoded with Base64, so I even tried decoding the string with Base64 after stripping off all the carriage returns, header and footer, which gave me error like this

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence

Below are some of the additional links I tried following up but have not been able to resolve.

- [JSch getting "invalid privatekey:" while trying to load an RSA private key by KeyPairGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276246/jsch-getting-invalid-privatekey-while-trying-to-load-an-rsa-private-key-by-ke)
- [Java - How to decode a Base64 encoded Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441276/java-how-to-decode-a-base64-encoded-certificate)
- [Converting a PEM private key file to a JAVA PrivateKey Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147566/converting-a-pem-private-key-file-to-a-java-privatekey-object)

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the answer.
Below post gave me a direction.

[JSch: addIdentity from private key stored on hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859100/jsch-addidentity-from-private-key-stored-on-hdfs)

To anyone else who is looking to solve a similar requirement, ensure that you are not stripping off the header, footer information. This took most of my time to debug as most of the blogs/SO posts directed towards stripping those characters. In Java, your string must have the carriage returns else you might get a very different byte array.

```
String  x = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n" + 
            "MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAtBk\Q/z4QAgk+LN3IUajqjUv7IucsCd4SebbQvah5t4WJ\r\n"
```

Convert the string to byte array using "US-ASCII" charset. Use following JSch method if you don't have a passphrase:

```
jsch.addIdentity("username",{bytearray of x},null, null)
```

Note: ensure that you are passing an unsigned byte array like:
Array (45, 45, 69,...)
and NOT
Array (45, -35, -125,...)